# clang: Fold expression and "expression result unused" warning

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, clang++

On clang 7.0 this code:

```
template <typename ... Ts> struct S {
  unsigned gs(unsigned i) {
    unsigned r = 0;
    ((r = unsigned(sizeof(Ts)), i-- == 0) || ...);
    return r;
  }
};

int foo(unsigned i) {
  S<int, double, long, float, char> s;
  return s.gs(3);
}
```

causes this warning:

```
~/dev/ta $ ~/bin/clang++ -c -std=c++17 fold-warning.cpp 
fold-warning.cpp:5:46: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    ((r = unsigned(sizeof(Ts)), i-- == 0) || ...);
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ^
```

Why? What expression is unused, by the compiler's logic?

Gcc 7.3/8.2 is happy with it.

Comment: There's nothing to unfold, here.

Comment: It is unfolding (r = unsigned(sizeof(Ts)), i-- == 0). When there is nothing to unfold, the compiler gives a different diagnostic. This is a slightly modified version of real code that works as expected. The only problem is the warning emitted by clang.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: In the real code, coming from a list of types Ts, I want the result of f<T>() for the type T that has the given index on the list. The shown code returns the sizeof of T. Previously I used a tuple<Ts...> and recursion over its types, but the code above offers a more compact solution.

Comment: @l.f. `(std::size_t[]){sizeof(Ts)...}[(std::min)(i,sizeof...(Ts)-1)]` -- get the size of the nth element of sizes.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Are you sure it compiles? IIRC casting to array type is not allowed in c++

Comment: @user643005 you can do this: `f<std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>>()`

Comment: @l.f. I just got brackets wrong and maybe need a typedef, but yes.

Comment: Well if `i` is allowed to be runtime then you need an array

Comment: Thanks, but `i' is a runtime parameter. The array solution is expensive because it needs to be built for every call and uses memory.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I believe compound literal isn't allowed in C++.

Comment: Checked: `(std::size_t[]){sizeof(Ts)...}[n]` compiles.

Comment: @user how many elements are we talking about?  The array is on the stack (automatic storage), and under as-if need not exist.  Btw do you want to call the first n-1 function calls and discard them?  Because we could avoid that too.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont That's actually a GNU extension: https://wandbox.org/permlink/gS9Y36afW1gUSvc2

Comment: @Yakk: the number of elements is arbitrary, but always small (the types correspond to the type parameters of functions, so it is rare to have more tan 10). I looked at the assembler of the production code and the array technique takes space and time. The function applied to the type with index `i' is not constexpr. If there is a solution that does not require to build the array nor compute the functions for the indexes <i, I'll like to learn about it.

Comment: BTW, previously the code used the recursive parameter pack walk technique, which allows to compute only the function that corresponds to the requested index, but that technique requires some helpers and opted instead for using the code above because is more concise and paying the performance penalty.

Comment: I'd just add an index sequence then do `(( (i==Is)&&((r=fn<Ts>()),true)),...)` or `( run_if( i==Is, [&r]{ r=fn<Ts>(); } ), ... );` or whatever.

Comment: @Yakk: I just came back to comment that `((i-- == 0 && (r=f<Ts>(), true)) || ...)` does the trick, but you already wrote that :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result of this line:

```
((r = unsigned(sizeof(Ts)), i-- == 0) || ...);
```

is a sequential `||` operation, whose result is not used, which caused the warning.

Casting to `void` to eliminate the warning:

```
(void)((r = unsigned(sizeof(Ts)), i-- == 0) || ...);
```